# How to change/modify result of a table based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I have a table,
Where one of the rows has only 3 types of answers, **'Yes or No'**.
I need to change the result set in such a way, if I get 'Yes', from database, I have to display only 'Y', If 'No', the result should be 'N'.

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════════╗
║ NAME         ║ FullTimeEmployee    ║   ROLE    ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════════╣
║ Phillips     ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ Devkonda     ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ Mike         ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ Sone         ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ Neemalla     ║ No                  ║ developer ║
║ Sirikonda    ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ Lingutla     ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ Chodella     ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ Chatterjee   ║ Expired             ║ developer ║
║ Glve         ║ No                  ║ developer ║
║ Ronla        ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
║ tejaswi      ║ Expired             ║ developer ║
║ Dasari       ║ No                  ║ developer ║
║ Reddy        ║ Expired             ║ developer ║
║ Salkeru      ║ Yes                 ║ developer ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Now, when I say `Select * from EmployeeRecords`

I need where `FullTimeEmployee = YES`, I need the result to be printed as Y.
I have another option to fix it on my Java side, but would love to know from SQL side too.

Comment: Decide which database you are using, then tag the question appropriately.  Then, study up a bit on SQL, particularly the `CASE` statement.

Comment: what do you want to show for Expired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gordon suggested you can you a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) statement to get the desired result.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN FullTimeEmployee = 'Yes' THEN 'Y' 
     WHEN FullTimeEmployee = 'No' THEN 'N'
     WHEN FullTimeEmployee = 'Expired' THEN 'E'
     ELSE 'Undefined'
     END AS 'isFullTimeEmployee'
FROM dbo.YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: `CASE FullTimeEmployee WHEN 'Yes' THEN 'Y' WHEN 'No' THEN 'N' END` would be less typing

Comment: @user1221684 Definitely an option just trying to illustrate an example

Comment: Awesome guys, thank you, and in the above script, you can put ',' at the end of line 6 and add some more attributes:
...END AS 'isFullTimeEmployee', ROLE as Designation... etc

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to just use `LEFT([value], 1)` in your case

```
SELECT
    NAME,       
    LEFT(FullTimeEmployee, 1) AS FullTimeEmployee,
    ROLE
FROM EmployeeRecords
```

Comment: Nice! Does LEFT work with both MySQL and SQL Server?